# VBA using a ListBox to multi select entire column in excel

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I have an excel file where I load the column headers dynamically from Row 2 across until I hit a null and put all those values into a list box transposed. This part is working as I expect it to.

My question is, how do I use the list box items to select the entire column that the named header exists in?

So in A2 B2 C2 I have the headers called Widget 1, 2, 3 respectively loaded into the listbox. Those load in order in the list box when the userform loads. In the list box, I would like to be able to click Widget 2 and 3 and have those entire columns selected. I don't want it hard coded, as I want it to be a selection as I could select widget 1 and 3 or any random selection as needed.

I could have as many as 50 widgets....so those will all load in the listbox on startup, I need to be able to select any of those values and have them select their corresponding column....

That is where I'm having issues, how to make the multi select happen.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDITS:

This is the code used on the Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
    'Figure out how many actual columns headers there are and then search for signal names

'Dim Lastcol As String
Dim FoundColumnRangeCalculated As Variant
Dim Lastcol As Variant
Dim FoundColumnRange As Variant

With ActiveSheet
Lastcol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
''MsgBox Lastcol
End With


'Convert numerical column location to letter value to use as dynamic range header lookup

Dim NumberToColumn As Variant
Dim SearchColumn
SearchColumn = Lastcol
NumberToColumn = Left(Cells(1, SearchColumn).Address(1, 0), InStr(1, Cells(1, SearchColumn).Address(1, 0), "$") - 1)
'MsgBox NumberToColumn

'Build the actual range from found column headers
FoundColumnRangeCalculated = "A2:" & (NumberToColumn & Lastcol)

'Transfer headers vertically to the list box for user to see

ListBox1.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range(FoundColumnRangeCalculated))
```

[Imported List Box Transposed on UserForm Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdhmE.png)

So now when I click or multi click (not shown in this image, but multi with choose options to be enabled) the item(s), I would like the corresponding column it represents to be selected when each item is clicked.

[Columns that the items are drawn from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKkdw.png)

Since they are built in "order" from left to right, I assume it is a 1:1 match and search and select, but I'm having trouble trying to sort that piece of it out..lots of examples about getting it's data, parsing, etc.....I just simply need a "When listbox items selected, use selection to enable its column".

The columns can't be hard coded for range as the headers could be A:F, A:AA, or A:ZZ.......so it has to be a dynamic matching.

Thanks to those that responded, hopefully this edited post and images satisfy the on hold status.

Comment: Where is the code you have already tried?

Comment: Also, Screenshot of data will make it easier to Understand.

Comment: I have edited the post and added pictures, hopefully this clarifies my initial inquiry

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple columns may try something like

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range, Sel As Range
Dim i As Long, Xval As Variant
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = Ws.Range(Ws.Cells(2, 1), Ws.Cells(2, Me.ListBox1.ListCount))

    For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Xval = Me.ListBox1.List(i)
            Set c = Rng.Find(Xval, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    If Sel Is Nothing Then
                    Set Sel = Ws.Columns(c.Column)
                    Else
                    Set Sel = Union(Sel, Ws.Columns(c.Column))
                    End If
                End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not Sel Is Nothing Then
    Sel.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to, both in single and multi select mode. I only made one change as my documents will only and absolutely will never be multi tabbed sheets and that change was: [code] Set Ws = ActiveSheet [\code]

Comment: This code has been working brilliantly, I am asking for additional help with it for a feature that has been brought to my attention. Is it possible to modify what is here to allow reordering of the listbox items with command buttons up/down when an item is selected and then have the columns themselves be "moved" to follow the listbox order? So if the default column incoming is 1,2,3 and I reorder it 1,3,2 then the column and all its data in the rows is "cut/pasted" or reordered with it? I see a lot of reordering, but I'd like to keep this code to do it....if possible. Please advise? TY

Comment: i could not get clearly how you want to reorder column. If simply want to reorder a column with up/down button then multi-select List Box is not needed and that would easier than swapping between columns. May please clarify more in this regard. However if the answer solved your problem may please accept the answer by clicking tick mark beside the answer to adhere to SO spirit.

Comment: The way my other code is written, it is using selection based on the listbox selections and pastes it to another workbook, and it does that in order after selections, so it doesn't remember what the order selection was, just the columns that were selected and pastes them out that way. So my thought is that adding up/down buttons to move the listbox item that the column should "move" or swapped as item is moved up or down without damaging existing data as it moves "up" or "down" the list. Does that makes sense? I can add some mock up images if needed. Thank you for responding.

Comment: To add a clarification, I would like the columns to "match" in left to right order the listbox from top to bottom (due to the transpose). This is because the data from the source may come in "out of order" where the listbox allows grouping of the "same" type of data together if the incoming file was not set up correctly (which I have no control over). So the reordering allows correction before it is moved to the next step. Hopefully this helps adds clarity and not confusion. Thank you.

Comment: I found this example that does exactly what I'm trying to do in terms of swapping the columns, I am wondering if this helps in terms of how it can be adapted to your code for expediency. Of course, if there is a faster better way, that will be the way it goes....  https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/swap-two-selected-cell-ranges-in-excel#disqus_thread

Answer (score -1):

In a case if you want to iterate through header's cells. It selects multiple columns for one widget if it's name matched more than once.

Works with ActiveSheet.

```
Dim result As Range
Dim criteria As String
Dim colcount As Integer

criteria = "widget1" ' Matching value
colcount = 10 ' Header columns count

For i = 1 To colcount
  ' Loop on 2nd row
  If Cells(2, i).Value = criteria Then
    ' If string matched with a cell's value
        If result Is Nothing Then
            ' if it's first match, set it as result column selection
            Set result = Columns(i)
        Else
            ' if it's not first match, add it to result selection
            Set result = Union(result, Columns(i))
        End If
  End If
Next

' Select result seletion
If Not result Is Nothing Then
    result.Select
End If
```

Comment: Instead of Loop, You can use `Range.Find` that will be Faster and Single Line approach. Also, you should add a bit of explanation in the answer, that will make it easier to Understand.

Comment: VBA is not going to like the `//` comments in your code.

Comment: Also there is a Listener `Private Sub ListBox1_Click()` or many more are there. So no need of a Button. :)

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I was able to utilize the answer in the previous post. I'll give this a try also as it is good to have multiple ways to do things. Best.